# Initial path is being appended to every Link when navigating nested routes in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a KeyboardEncyclopedia component which contains nested routes to individual components. E.g. the component "Introduction" would have the path "keyboard-encyclopedia/introduction". Every component belonging to the KeyboardEncyclopedia component starts with the path "/keyboard-encyclopedia".

My component KeyboardEncyclopedia contains two components:

- KeyboardEncyclopediaNavbar - contains `Links` that take the url to build the nested path.
- KeyboardEncyclopediaRoutes - contains `Routes` that take the path to build the nested path.

KeyboardEncyclopedia calls the `useRouteMatch()` hook and passes the url and path to these components respectively.

I also have a Navbar component that contains routes for `Links` outside of the KeyboardEncyclopedia.

KeyboardEncyclopedia component:

```
const KeyboardEncyclopedia = () => {
  const { path, url } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
   <KeyboardEncyclopediaNavbar url={url} /> //Pass url for Links
    <Switch>
     <Route exact path={path} component={Introduction} /> //Return as default page upon entering KeyboardEncyclopedia
     <KeyboardEncyclopediaRoutes path={path} /> //Pass path for Routes
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

KeyboardEncyclopediaNavbar component:

```
const KeyboardEncyclopediaNavbar = (props) => {
  const url = props.url; //Url is passed down as props
  const categoryList = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Getting Started",
      chapters: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Introduction to Mechanical Keyboards",
          link: "introduction",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Switches",
          link: "switches",
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Layouts and Sizes",
          link: "layouts-and-sizes",
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "Plates and PCBs",
          link: "plates-and-pcbs",
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "Stabilizers",
          link: "stabilizers",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Keyboard Modifications",
      chapters: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Switch Modifications",
          link: "switch-modifications",
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  const categories = categoryList.map((category) => {
    let categoryChapters = category.chapters.map((chapter) => (
      <NavbarLink key={chapter.id} to={`${url}/${chapter.link}`}> //Links are built here
        {chapter.name}
      </NavbarLink>
    ));

    return (
      <NavbarCategory key={category.id}>
        <NavbarTitle>{category.name}</NavbarTitle>
        {categoryChapters}
      </NavbarCategory>
    );
  });

  return <Navbar>{categories}</Navbar>;
};

export default KeyboardEncyclopediaNavbar;
```

KeyboardEncyclopediaRoutes component:

```
const KeyboardEncyclopediaRoutes = (props) => {
  const path = props.path; //Path is passed down as props
  const routes = [
    {
      name: "introduction",
      component: Introduction,
    },
    {
      name: "layouts-and-sizes",
      component: LayoutsAndSizes,
    },
    {
      name: "plates-and-pcbs",
      component: PlatesAndPCBs,
    },
    {
      name: "keycaps",
      component: Keycaps,
    },
    {
      name: "stabilizers",
      component: Stabilizers,
    },
    {
      name: "switches",
      component: Switches,
    },
    {
      name: "switch-modfications",
      component: SwitchModifications,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      {routes.map((route, index) => (
        <Route path={`${path}/${route.name}`} key={index} component={route.component} /> //Routes are built here
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default KeyboardEncyclopediaRoutes;
```

Navbar component:

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const navbarData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "The Keyboard Encyclopedia",
      path: "keyboard-encyclopedia",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "My Keyboards",
      path: "my-keyboards",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "About",
      path: "about",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: "Contact",
      path: "contact",
    },
  ];

  return (
   <NavBar>
    <NavBarLogo to="/">Keyboard Corner</NavBarLogo>
    <NavMenu>
     {navbarData.map((item) => {
      return (
       <li key={item.id}>
        <NavLink to={item.path}>
         <span>{item.title}</span>
        </NavLink>
       </li>
      );
      })}
    </NavMenu>
   </NavBar>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

The problem I am facing is when I click any `Link` in the KeyboardEncyclopediaNavbar, the initial path "/keyboard-encyclopedia" persists to all other `Links` that are present - in this case, it's doing this to every link in my main app's Navbar (except the "/" `Link` that leads to the home page). For example, upon clicking a `Link` in the KeyboardEncyclopediaNavbar then clicking on the About `Link` in my app's Navbar, I now see the url is "/keyboard-encyclopedia/about" when it should be "/about".

I notice the `useRouteMatch()` path is setting the initial path, because when I hardcode the path to something else instead of using the `props.path` in the KeyboardEncyclopediaRoutes component, the initial path changes. I want to figure out why it appends this path to every other `Link` at this point.

I want to take advantage of being able to build dynamic links and routes, but it seems I'm missing something crucial here to do with React router. If anyone could figure this out, I would be super duper grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem thanks to /u/MGTakedown on reddit. Props goes to this dude!

Reddit post:
https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/lbpwjp/initial_path_is_being_appended_to_every_link/

For the Navbar links, I added a forward slash before the given path so that the link paths refer to the base url instead of referring back to the previous path:

```
  const routes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "The Keyboard Encyclopedia",
      path: "/keyboard-encyclopedia", //Added forward slash before paths
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "My Keyboards",
      path: "/my-keyboards",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "About",
      path: "/about",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: "Contact",
      path: "/contact",
    },
  ];
```